# How to htaccess redirect urls to .html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying to find a code to 301 redirect pages like this in htaccess file:

www.example.com/view-profiles

To

www.example.com/view-profiles.html

But I need to make sure it does not conflict with the /index.html redirect rule I have there and also could be applied as a rule to many urls at once.

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
redirect 301 /view-profiles http://www.example.com/view-profiles.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the files that have a .html extension to be the target of such a redirect, you have to use mod_rewrite

**This is untested!**
For testing I recommend to first replace the 301 with a 302, because your browser might remember the 301 setting and won't access the server to be 'rewritten'.

In your .htaccess you need something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If in subdirectory uncomment the following and 
  #   replace subdir with your subdirectory
  #Rewritebase /subdir

  # This will rewrite if request_filename is not a directory (!-d)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # RewriteCond is with AND per default
  # Only if request + .html extension is a file (-f)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f

  # If both above conditions are true this rule is followed
  # ^(.*)$: Regular Expression Match everything `.*` in the request 
  #   from start `^` to the end `$` 
  # Brackets mean: capture the text if matched
  # $1.html Append .html to the captured text from the Rule
  # [L,R=301]: L=Last don't try to rewrite any other rule that comes below
  #            R=301 Redirect and set the HTTP Status code to 301
  RewriteRule    ^(.*)$     $1.html     [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

**Again! This is untested!**

Answer (score 0):

If you only need rule for /view-profiles` URI then it will work:

```
RewriteRule ^view-profiles/?$ view-profiles.html [L,NC,R=301]
```